# coordinate dose not show on leaflet with django

Tags: leaflet

I want to show marker location on leaflet in Django 
actually it work one time only when i put code on our_layar function
but as i said it work for one time.
i want to put code on somewhere to get it work. the code of show marker
is between //////location of marker/////

```
 <div id="map">
{% leaflet_map "gis" callback="window.our_layar" %}
   </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var countriesLayer ;
  var KSA_POP;
   var div_circle = L.divIcon({ className: 'circle'});


   //////location of marker/////
  var map = L.map('gis'); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<I think there is problem
  var lat = 0.0;
  var lon = 0.0;
  var marker;
  var onDrag = function (e) {
   var latlng = marker.getLatLng();

      document.getElementById('outlat').innerHTML = latlng.lat;
       document.getElementById('outlon').innerHTML = laenter code 
  heretlng.lng;
     };



  var onClick = function(e) {
map.off('click', onClick); //turn off listener for map click
marker = L.marker(e.latlng, {
  icon: div_circle,
 draggable:'true',
 opacity:1

   }).addTo(map);
  lat = e.latlng.lat;
  lon = e.latlng.lng;
  document.getElementById('outlat').innerHTML = e.latlng.lat;
  document.getElementById('outlon').innerHTML = e.latlng.lng;
  marker.on('drag', onDrag);
    //marker.on('drag', onDrag);
       };

      map.on('click', onClick);

      //////location of marker/////
```

this is our_layar function that called by callback

```
      function our_layar(map,options){ // load all geojason file


   KSA_POP = L.geoJson(
    KSA_POP_Cities,
    {style :countriesStyle
  }

  ).addTo(map);



  L.geoJSON(MOHfacilities, {
    pointToLayer(feature, latlng) {
   marker= L.marker(latlng, {
   icon: div_circle,
  draggable:'true',
   opacity:0.5
     }); 

     return marker;
      }
      }).addTo(map);


  }
```

Comment: any help pleas  > <   ?

Comment: I am waiting, Is there any hint or help ? thank you